# Parameter in controller is always null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

The parameter that I send to controller is always null.

```
   $("#btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate").on("click", function (e) {

            var idSelector = function () { return this.id; };
            var selectedDamages = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
            console.log(selectedDamages);

             var action_url = '@Url.Action("GenerateInvoiceDamage", "TimberMonitor", new { Area = "", ids = "CMP_ID" })';
             action_url = action_url.replace("CMP_ID", selectedDamages);
            window.location = action_url;
        });
```

I need to send the selectedDamages list(which contain a list of ids) to controller, but in the controller the ids parameter is always null.

[image]

I have tried to change in the controller method the parameter type to `List<string>`. I have checked to be the same name for the parameter in controller and in the view, too.
what can I check in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of `selectedDamages` is an array, you need to generate a url where the query string is `?ids=x&ids=y&ids=z`, and the parameter in your method needs to be `IEnumerable<T>`, for example

```
public ActionResult GenerateInvoiceDamage(IEnumerable<string> ids)
```

To generate the query string, you can use the jQuery `param()` function

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("GenerateInvoiceDamage", "TimberMonitor", new { Area = "" })';
var url = baseUrl + '?' + $.param({ ids: selectedDamages }, true);
location.href = url;
```